# Check a text field in a marketo form for acceptable URL's

Tags: javascript, forms, marketo

I have a Marketo form with one field called sharedURL. I set this as a text field because the URL field is too restrictive, as you may have guest it is a field which allows people to input a URL. The field should only accept certain domains before moving on to the defined Landing page. Lets assume the only acceptable domains are www.marketo.com, http://www.marketo.com, https://www.marketo.com etc (all variations of the domain). I looked at multiple suggested solutions on various external sites and marketo sites but couldnt manage to tweak the code to fit my requirement. This is what I got (inserted in the HTML in a guided landing page template) my Form and field details are (if its needed). My solution did not work... any help appreciated....

"Id":6466,"Name":"sharedURL","Datatype":"string","Maxlength":512,"

```
(function() {
  // Domains that can only be used
  var validDomains = [
      'https://info.marketo.com',
      'https://www.marketo.com',
      'http://www.marketo.com',
      'info.marketo.com',
      'www.marketo.com',
    ],
    MktoForms2.whenReady(function(form) {
      form.onValidate(function() {
        var url = form.vals().sharedURL;
        if (url) {
          if (!isurlGood(url)) {
            form.submitable(false);
            var urlElem = form.getFormElem().find("#sharedURL");
            form.showErrorMessage("You must use an approved Domain.", urlElem);
          } else {
            form.submitable(true);
          }
        }
      });
    });

  function isurlGood(url) {
    for (var i = 0; i < validDomains.length; i++) {
      var domain = validDomains[i];
      if (url.indexOf(domain) != -1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
})();
```

Comment: It's easier to identifier bugs if your code is formatted correctly. I've formatted it for you but you should really make it a habit of always writing formatted code.

Comment: Thanks Mike, appreciate the effort!

Comment: I suspect you have a problem with capturing the url from the form.